# Smartface 4.5 ios app startup message with individual license

Tags: smartface.io

I have purchased individual license but still appears ios app startup message  "Developer Information"
"This Application is created with Smartface Community Edition......"

There is no problem with Android. 
How to eliminate ios app also?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to using existing licenses which were community. I have created new app license and problem solved!